# Sockets-Double printing on client side

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, chat

I'm developing a simple chat app using sockets. It's client-server driven.
Everything works perfect, except for this bug I'm unable to find: if I'm the first client to connect to the server, every message I receive is printed just once on the screen (as it's supposed to be). Nevertheless, if I'm the second client who connects, every message I receive is printed twice, the third client see his messages three times, and so on. I'm really going crazy because of this:

When I receive something through the socket, I print it like this:

```
printf (" >%s \n", received);
```

Hence, if I get the message hello, sent by the user "charles" I print the message ">charles: hello", what amazes me is that the duplicate prints don't have the ">" character I added (the duplicate will be "charles: hello") , thus making me unable to find where the printing is being made (the `printf()` above is the only `printf()` I have in my code).

I'll appreciate any help. Here is the part of the code that receives from socket:

```
while (1) {
    recv(newsockfd, recibido, 255, 0);
    printf (">%s \n",recibido);
}
```

This code is executed by a thread.

Thanks, guys.

Here's the full code of the client:

```
void *Atender(void *estructura){
   DATOS *info;
   info = (DATOS *)estructura;
   int newsockfd=info->socket;
   char recibido[255];
   memset(recibido,1,255);
   while (1){
       recv(newsockfd, recibido, 255, 0);
       printf (">%s \n",recibido);
       memset(recibido,0,255);
   }
}

main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    char *server;
    Hilos = malloc((200)*sizeof(pthread_t));

    /* Remember the program name for error messages. */
    programname = argv[0];

    //Realizo lectura e imprimo para chequear que se leyo todo bien.
    lectura(argv,argc);

    /* Who's the server? */
    server=host;


    /* Get the address of the server. */
    bzero(&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server);
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(puerto));

    /* Open a socket. */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        fatalerror("can't open socket");

    /* Connect to the server. */
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr,
        sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
        fatalerror("can't connect to server");

    enviarInfoInicial(sockfd,nombre,"Actual");

    char buff[200];
    memset(buff,1,200);


    //Creacion del hilo que se quedara siempre escuchando
    DATOS d;
    d.socket=sockfd;
    pthread_create(&Hilos[iterador_hilos],NULL,Atender,(void *)&d);
    iterador_hilos++;

    //El que no es un hilo se queda siempre esperando por si se quiere
    //introducir un comando
    while (1) {
        fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin);
        mandarInstruccion(sockfd,buff);
        if ((buff[0] == 'f') & (buff[1] == 'u') & (buff[2] == 'e')){
            printf("Cchat se ha cerrado. \n");
            close(sockfd);
            exit(0);
        }

        memset(buff,1,200);
    }
}
```

The code is in Spanish, but the general idea is understandable. The `DATOS` structure is just the structure i pass to the created thread, and only contains the socket from which that thread will be reading (the `while(1)` posted previously). "ATENDER" is the procedure the thread will execute.

Here's the relevant code from the server:

```
void EjecutarInstruccion(char tipo[],char argumento[],char usuario[]) {
    if (!strcmp(tipo,"men")) {
        char sala[20];
        char total[300];
        memset(total,0,300);
        strcpy(sala,ObtenerSalaUsuario(usuario));
        int i=0;
        for (i;i<200;i++) {
            if (!strcmp((lusuarios[i].sala),sala)) {
                strcat(total,usuario);
                strcat(total,": ");
                strcat(total,argumento);
                send (lusuarios[i].socket, total, strlen(total)+1, 0 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ON the server side I have an array of Users, each user contains his username, the chat room he is in and his socket (the fd). When the server needs to send a message, I go through the array of users and send the message to that user only if he's in the same chat room.
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to post your client & server code if you want us to spot a bug in it.

Comment: Ok, i'll add it right now

Comment: You should post the relevant server code since that is what is likely sending the same message.

Comment: I really checked the server. it sends the message just once. Neverthelles i'll add it to the post.

Answer (score 2):

You don't check how many bytes `recv` returned. It does not necessarily read all data that is outstanding. You probably need to read in a loop until all bytes are received.

Comment: It's been sold guys. some memset that was missing. thank you anyways.

Comment: Same for `send()`. The OP consequently ignores the **relevant** values returned by `recv()` and `send()`.